# Jmeter: Is it possible to run a particular thread group after all the other thread group gets completed

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, beanshell, blazemeter

In JMeter, I have a requirement where I want to run a particular thread group after all the other thread groups complete their run, I know the tearDown thread group has the similar behavior but unfortunately, the logic has to be part of my regular thread.

Let's say there are 4 thread groups A,B,C & D in my test plan and I want the thread group D only to be executed after A, B & C will complete their run.

**Can we achieve this without using "setup, teardown & Run groups one at a time" ??**

Problem ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: Is this some kind of interview question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest 2 options:

1. Use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/). See [example test plan](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) for details.
2. If for some reason you are not in position to use JMeter Plugins you can achieve the same using JMeter Properties like:

   - When Thread Group A finishes set a JMeter Property, i.e. `ThreadGroupADone=true` using __setProperty() function like

     ```
     ${__setProperty(ThreadGroupADone,true,)}
     ```
   - In Thread Group D:

     - Add [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) at the beginning of the Thread Group and use the following condition:

       ```
       ${__javaScript("${__P(ThreadGroupADone,)}"=="false",)}
       ```
     - Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler as a child of the While Controller and configure it to pause for a reasonable amount of seconds, i.e. 5 so each 5 seconds While Controller will check `ThreadGroupADone` property value and if it is still `false` - sleep for another 5 seconds. When property value will become `true` - Thread Group D will proceed.